# trimming the output of difflib.Differ

Tags: python, unit-testing, compare

I want to have more informative message for `assertEqual` mismatches and I am using `difflib.Differ` for that.  However, when the file is big, it returns way too much info.

How do I achieve something like `diff`s *windowing* that only shows a few context lines?

```
@@ -155,6 +155,8 @@ except (ImportError,) as e:
     raise
+tst
+
 class KeepTextFilter(object):
     def __init__(self, regexes = [], f_notify=None):
```

This is my test code:

```
def get_data():

    left, right = [],[]
    for num in range(0,10):
        lmark = rmark = " "
        if not (num % 5):
            lmark, rmark = "L", "R"
        left.append("%02d%s" % (num, lmark))
        right.append("%02d%s" % (num,rmark))

    return left, right

from difflib import Differ

differ = Differ()
left, right = get_data()
print(left)
print(right)    

output = "\n".join(differ.compare(left, right))
print(output)
```

and this is what the output looks like (given bigger lists, it will put out everything)

```
['00L', '01 ', '02 ', '03 ', '04 ', '05L', '06 ', '07 ', '08 ', '09 ']
['00R', '01 ', '02 ', '03 ', '04 ', '05R', '06 ', '07 ', '08 ', '09 ']
- 00L
+ 00R
  01 
  02 
  03 
  04 
- 05L
+ 05R
  06 
  07 
  08 
  09
```

How could I achieve have a window of say `1`. i.e.

```
- 00L
+ 00R
  01 
  04 
- 05L
+ 05R
  06
```

I am thinking hacking something together with a `deque(maxlen=1)` but thought I would ask - this seems like an obvious requirement.  I looked at the constructor for `Differ()` and `compare`'s signature, but neither have this option.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with

```
class DiffFormatter(difflib.Differ):

    def _window(self, lines, window=None):
        try:

            if not window:
                return lines
            if not isinstance(window, int):
                raise TypeError("window has to be an int")

            #remember, at most, `window` # of lines
            dq = deque(maxlen=window)
            cntr = 0

            res = []

            for line in lines:

                if line[0] in ("+","-"):
                    #reset cntr
                    cntr = window
                    while True:
                        #add `before` context lines
                        try:
                            #try if res.extend(dq) works
                            res.append(dq.popleft())
                        except (IndexError,) as e:
                            break
                    res.append(line)
                elif cntr > 0:
                    #`after` context
                    #cntr, while > 0 adds line to res
                    cntr -= 1
                    res.append(line)
                else:
                    #this line won't be used, unless a later line
                    #requires it in context.
                    dq.append(line)
            return res
        except (Exception,) as e:
            raise

    def format(self, exp, got, window=None):
        try:
            exp_ = exp.splitlines()
            got_ = got.splitlines()
            lines = self.compare(exp_, got_)

            if window:
                lines2 = self._window(lines, window)
            else:
                lines2 = list(lines)

            msg = "\n".join(lines2)
            msg = msg.strip()
            if msg and msg[1] != " ":
                msg = "  %s" % (msg) 
            return msg 

        except (Exception,) as e:
            raise
```